# React Joyride open up pages in app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm using react joyride as a tutorial/walkthrough for our application.  Does anyone know of a way within navigation to have the joyride open up other pages and navigate around the entire app?

So for example, we have a 'create record' section in our app that allows a user to create data (using a multiple step process), but it's a 3 step process incorporating a breadcrumb stepper with validation in each step.
I'm a bit confused as to how to show the user these steps?

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Comment: You should check out [Hopscotch by LinkedIn](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/#multipage-tour-example). They support multi-page tours.

Comment: Did you ever learn the answer to this?